# Find closest points between two lists of [[X,Y], [X,Y], ...] coordinates, in vanilla python

Tags: python, list, sorting, compare, coordinates

I have two lists of [x, y] coordinates (trimmed for ease of understanding).

How can I find the closest point between the two lists.
ie. **if they're beacons on two islands coastlines, how can I find the two closest beacons?**

```
coords1 = [[0.5896793603897095, 2.4871931076049805], [0.6417439579963684, 2.4339494705200195], [0.6417439579963684, 2.4871931076049805], [0.6157116293907166, 2.407327651977539], [0.6677762269973755, 2.4605712890625], [0.6157116889953613, 2.4871931076049805], [0.5896793603897095, 2.407327651977539], [0.6417439579963684, 2.407327651977539], [0.6547601222991943, 2.4738821983337402], [0.6547601222991943, 2.4472603797912598], [0.6026955246925354, 2.4871931076049805]]


coords2 = [[0.7719054222106934, 2.4605712890625], [0.7198407649993896, 2.407327651977539], [0.7979376912117004, 2.4605712890625], [0.7458730936050415, 2.4605712890625], [0.7198408246040344, 2.4339494705200195], [0.7198408246040344, 2.3807055950164795], [0.7328569293022156, 2.4472603797912598], [0.7849215269088745, 2.4605712890625], [0.7588892579078674, 2.4605712890625], [0.7458730936050415, 2.4472603797912598], [0.7198407649993896, 2.4472603797912598], [0.7198407649993896, 2.394016742706299], [0.7198407649993896, 2.4206385612487793]]
 
closestCoord1 = [] 
closestCoord2 = []
```

I have tried sorting by highest/lowest X and Y values and comparing but had no luck, and I'm unsure if that's the right route. The only leads I can find are for single values in lists, or importing a custom python library. I need this in vanilla python.

Comment: For clarification you want the closest point from coords1 to coords2, right? As you defined two lists below. The straight forward way would be to iterate over both lists and keep track of the lowest distance and indices and update it if you find a closer one.

Comment: In case you're not aware distance is: (x1-x2)^2 + (y1-y2)^2. You can neglect the square root if you want. Minima wont change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to find the distance between each pair of points. Then find the minimum.

You can do it in a single step using the `key` argument to the `min` function. `itertools.product` is used to find all pairs of points, but `itertools` is a built-in module:

```
import itertools

def sqdist(pts):
    p1 = pts[0]
    p2 = pts[1]
    return (p1[0]-p2[0])**2 + (p1[1]-p2[1])**2

point_pairs = itertools.product(coords1, coords2)

closestCoord1, closestCoord2 = min(point_pairs, key=sqdist)
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##lZRNbttADIX3OsUs7dQ1@DMkhwWyyjEMoyhiFxWSWIKkLHJ6h7LVIAEko9VCAKlPJN8bYtq34U9z4vO5fmmbbkj1cOyGpnnuq@qxabpDj@k@7XawleJqzgpc3MBlk2ibi6EzgilkLyD7TQpSM1pmF3NX1pIvJLNnzwZCAOi3yPmaKIao5OxgqHohwZhMBd1M2CdQzUyJ1N3Y5DqmQvxNxUHpa71S3IUVebnzrO7ZznNiZkHJ0QKJyB09X3sbl0LohZktA90gs1EMY26OJF4mEkKxCGV1EpZ5J/fV30Ol6VAtCJAcDRDUOS@4FVQJKZrdPWxYdn@cik1jMkQDWKyXpRjD6KpARrnZtoQoyMD5xiLNkVwgKHEB1GwfJFORMMkZQrTosqVWsgcRvkIpMfHSkFJiiyiOHayo/Zfk@b5zZv8zGe6EXstk0dv9RkkC5bACKfYkTi22I1XV4fg7Hep@WLVDv/5RpXja8QaIcAf7a0xTjNe4Ow6v3SmtWgzie0vxXt/dUfp2SeElhZdUVbVNfRp@tr/qro8iH3fNtu2aw@vjsJqunE2a1nQdC/vc9Md@eBgT44dP4TjIS31afaq6SU/Ht/tRQfzadpFffSmwnknS@nx@Bw)

Comment: Magnificent, thank you. Marked as correct! Out of interest: instead of getting the [x,y] coordinate value from each list, is there an easy way to get the list indexes instead?

Comment: You could get the product of `enumerate()` on both lists. Be sure to change `sqdist` to index into the item correctly though!